# Where to put loading of HashTable

Tags: node.js, rest, hashtable

I have an nodejs application having some REST APIs and is working well.

One of the API, say /billinginfo POST, receives a client code and a piece of data via JSON format, and it will make a API call, to another service, say /client GET, that returns country of the client, and it then inserts the data into the database.

I later found out that, for performance improvements, I can actually load all the client's countries into a HashTable 1st with key being the client code with one API call that return all the clients and avoid calling that /client GET API many times and will look into the HashTable instead.

My question is now, where do I normally put codes loading the HashTable to be used by the /billinginfo POST API?

**Update:**

The country and the client info is on AWS AURORA in the cloud of another system and /billinginfo POST is writing to a on-premise MS SQL database hence I must make calls to /client GET API.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is put the data of countries in your database and put the proper indexing, and after that query from your database.It'll be quicker than calling third party API.

Comment: thanks @ayushmittal, unfortunately the country and the client info is on AWS AURORA in the cloud of another system and /billinginfo POST is writing to a on-premise MS SQL database.